# Change root folder of pelican content

Tags: python, html, pelican

I'm using `pelican` to generate my website and I want to organize my files like this:

```
content
   blog
       article1.md
       article2.md
   pages
       about.md
       index.md
```

I'm trying to get a static landing page, `index.html` and a blogroll to the blog itself, so I configured my `pelicanconf.py` as

```
SITEURL = u'http://mywebsite.org'
PATH = 'content'
ARTICLE_PATHS = ['blog']
ARTICLE_URL = "blog/{slug}.html"
#ARTICLE_SAVE_AS = "blog/{slug}.html"
INDEX_URL = 'blog'
INDEX_SAVE_AS = 'blog_index.html'

OUTPUT_PATH='output/blog'
```

However, when I access the root directory (`mywebsite.org`) I only get a subfolder, `blog`. Inside this link there is a list of the articles, but when I click on the article I get a 404. I also tried using the suggestion of the [FAQ](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.5.0/faq.html#how-can-i-override-the-generated-url-of-a-specific-page-or-article) to get an `index.html` page on the `pages` folder, with the content:

```
Title: Welcome to My Site
URL:
save_as: index.html

Thank you for visiting. Welcome!
```

Unfortunately then not even the `blog` link appears. What am I doing wrong? How can I have a static landing page with some links, including the `blog` that is generated by pelican, with the content organized in the folders?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem recently with the missing subfolders. Eventually I saw that in a recent [changelog](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/blob/master/docs/changelog.rst), they replaced the `PAGES` context variable for themes in favor of `pages`. Have a look at your template and see which variable it's using. If it's the all caps, you can just lowercase it and you should see the subfolders you expect to see.